# Tensorflow GPU application crashes Jupyter notebook kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow

We are running Tensorflow applications on GPU using multiple Jupyter notebooks.  Every once in a while one of the runs crashes the notebook, with the simple notification that "The kernel has crashed...".

When we placed the code into a python .py file, the stderr output was

```
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops_3d.cc:369] Check failed:   stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
Aborted
```

In another run the stderr reported:

```
F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc:296] GPU->CPU Memcpy failed
```

The problem is that the tensorflow applications are grabbing a lot of memory.  In Linux you can run `top` to see what is going on.  On our machine we saw that each tensorflow process was grabbing `0.55t`!

When you run the process inside a Jupyter notebook and do not shutdown the notebook, the notebook does not release the memory.  At some point you will run a process that cannot access memory and it will die.  If you are running inside a notebook it will only tell you that the kernel has died.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to place the following snippet before you import tensorflow:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
```

**Added after @ Nicolas comment**

Yes this disables GPU!  Which is not what is wanted.

Comment: Just to be clear, the snippet will disable the make the GPU cards not visible to the TensorFlow process and therefore TensorFlow won't run on GPU.